# How is eventloop in node.js/expressjs handles this code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to understand how this code work in node.js/expressjs framework.
My assumtion is like this:
1. A request comes in and it is handled with thatRequest route.
2. B request comes in and the thatRequest handles that too.
3. There are no shared variables between A and B connection.

The connections are treated privately. They share some common configs but nothing more.
A comes for a computer and B comes from another computer.
My understanding is that each time checkStates is called it starts with virgin version variables defined outside the function.

What will be the case of using node cluster which spawn a new process for each processor an environment has?

```
// in thatRequest.js file
const RETRY_EVERY = 3; // seconds
const MAX_RETRY = 10; // maximum retry times
let checkInterval = 0;
let remainingRetry = 0;

async function checkStates (req, res) {
    remainingRetry = !remainingRetry ? MAX_RETRY * 1 : remainingRetry--;

    if (remainingRetry < 1) {
      clearInterval(checkInterval);
    }
  }
}
const request = (req, res) => {
  checkInterval = setInterval(() => {
    checkStates(req, res);
  }, RETRY_EVERY * 1000);

  return checkStates(req, res);

};

export default request;

// in a routes.js file
import thatRequest from 'thatRequest';
export default (req, res) => {
    thatRequest(req, res);
};
```

Comment: well, no, all calls to checkStates will use the same variables that you defined outside of it, including calls originating from different clients.

Comment: so basicaly everytime checkStates is called it will use :
`const RETRY_EVERY = 3; // seconds
const MAX_RETRY = 10; // maximum retry times
let checkInterval = 0;
let remainingRetry = 0;`
**any idea or link that backs this assumtion** it is also my assumtion but do not know how to explain it

Comment: well, no, other than the javascript spec or mdn, that's just how it works... relatively basic. All requests use the same thread, same shared variables, same modules, etc.

Comment: This  is true some share or not variables. Depending on how those vars are declared. At the moment ** remainingRetry ** is declared in outer scope of checkStates and is modified in inner /closure scope.
The next request which arrives will it use ** remainingRetry ** modified in the closure or the one defined outside.

All i know and experienced so far is that the ** remainingRetry ** get into checkStates on 0 for each individual connection.  I might be wrong but i want to understand why.

Comment: My explanation for the above sentence is based on the fact that each request that comes in is treated individually top to bottom, from req.open to res.close.